# Show a WindowForm in another WindowForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to show a form in another form. Please take attention I do not want to use `Show()` or `ShowDialog()` for second form. 
I want to do something like this:

```
Form1.Forms.Add(Form2);
```

which `Form1.Forms` is a `Form[]` of Form1.

I've seen something like this but unfortunately I can not find that again. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you're looking for is [Multiple document interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You'll create a MDI parent form, then add childs into it. Suggested link has step by step tutorial on how to implement it.